# Modify a multi-level nested list to make a single-level list

Tags: python, list

If I have a list formed by the command `dic.keys()` like this:

```
[
  "['my', 'modem']", "['technical', 'schematics']", "['still', 'glad']",
  "['spent', 'calling']", "['most', 'feared']", "['the', 'sysop']",
  "['s', 'mystique']", "['had', 'been']", "['of', 'doom']",
  "['i', 'hooked']", "['in', 'california']", "['my', 'ego']",
  "['until', 'my']", "['didn', 't']"
]
```

The keys are formed by `str()`,so it looks like list, but is a string.
My question is, how can you separate each item to make it look like this?

```
[ 'my', 'modem', 'techenical', ... ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Just do a pattern matching for each string:

```
res = []
for item in l:
    m = re.match("\['(.*)', '(.*)'\]", item)
    res.append(m.group(1))
    res.append(m.group(2))
#>>> res - ['my', 'modem', 'technical', ...]
```